Can't write in a textbox I have designed in Powerpoint slidemaster
I have downloaded a powerpoint slide template. In the slide master, I want to create an additional layout. I add a textbox to the template in the slide master. However, when I switch out of the slide master to use the layout in my document, I can't type in the textbox that I have added to the layout template in the slide master mode. What's wrong? I thought it might be that the textbox has gone under some other objects, so I tried "bring to front" feature but it didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I made a small change and I think it must be now comprehensible for anyone who is familiar with Power Point, specially the slide master feature.

The textbox when added to the master slide won't be editable when used on "normal" slides as you have already discovered. The placeholder is editable while the textbox is not. You can use a placeholder as a possible solution.
